# Virtual list view not checking items that are not visible in GUI

Tags: c#, listview

I have a `virtual list view` and each row has a `checkbox`, I have a master checkbox that checks all the rows in the grid, this works fine until I filter some of the rows (all rows currently unchecked) and then load back all rows into the list view and then click my master checkbox to select all rows, all rows appear selected until I scroll down and then the rows I filtered are not selected but the rest are. Now this sounds like an obvious bug but if I make my window bigger so I can see at least one of the rows that was filtered and then click the master checkbox the visible row is now checked in other words rows that are not on screen that were previously filtered remain unchecked while rows that were not filtered and were not on screen are checked.

Any ideas why this would be?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using a virtual list box, you should in my opinion operate on the actual data instead of the list box entries anyway. That might solve your problem already.

Comment: WinForms, ASP or WPF? It makes a big difference :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that when you filter the rows an attribute or o flag changes that prevents the master checkbox to select them. Try posting some of your code to help us.